# populate dropdownlist on button click using jquery

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my application ,I have a dropdownlist which is to be populated on button click.I tried some code which is working fine on document.ready but its not working on button click..

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=btn.ClientID %>").bind('click',function () {
            //
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "gridpaging.aspx/binddropdown",
                data: "{}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data.d, function (key, value) {
                        $("#ddl").append($("<option> </option>").val(value.UserId).html(value.UserName));
                    });
                    //

                },
                error: function (result) {

                    alert("Error occured");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Please let me know where i went wrong..Thanks in advance..

Comment: what is your returned json look like?

Comment: It gives me an alert 'Error Occured'..

Comment: What is the actual error? for your `error` event handler, change it to `function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert(xhr.status); alert(thrownError);}` so you can see the actual error message.

Comment: @RayCheng the error says undefined..

Comment: how about change `alert(thrownError)` to `alert(xhr.responseText)`? also, what is the `xhr.status`? is it 200 or 500?

Comment: @RayCheng for both its undefined..

Comment: When you debug, put a break point at `gridpaging.aspx/binddropdown` and make sure it actually hit it. I think your `post` is not getting to that method.

Comment: @RayCheng I tried that its going inside that function and that function is working fine..

Comment: That beats me. It appears the button is firing the `post` and your server side code is returning data. But somewhere alone the line, the `success` event didn't get called and `error` is called. I suggest you focus on the `error` handler and try to see what he actual error is.

Comment: @RayCheng you are right.But when i run this on IE the dropdown is populated but visible only for seconds ,It blinks and disappears..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25267/discussion-between-ray-cheng-and-smith269)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are mixing up two techniques here. One is ejs: <%=btn.ClientID %>, which is a templating engine to serve up dynamic content. The other is your jquery. What may solve your issue is to add a class to that button, rather than relying on your btn.ClientID, and then use $(".myClass").bind('click', function() ...

See if that solves your problem. If not, I'll need a bit more information. Is the ejs being compiled on the server side or on the client side? Are you using backbone or some kind of front end framework that's compiling the ejs?

Comment: I tried that too but its not working..But in IE when i click the button its populating but again it goes off..

Answer (score 0):

yourdeveloperfriend is almost right, except `<%=btn.ClientID %>` is not ejs, but asp.net snippet which is most probably used in the wrong place. I can imaging only one scenario in which this could work, and that is when this JS code is located in you aspx file, but most probably you have it in a separate js file. So do what yourdeveloperfriend said, and put a class on the button, and use that as a selector in your JS.

Comment: and what do you mean by 'it goes off'?

Comment: Then maybe the problem is somewhere else. Is there a change event handler for the dropdown?
And what about other browsers? Is it working in FF or Chrome?

Comment: @AndrasToth I mean when i click the button the dropdown is populated and its visible ony for seconds,that too only in internet explorer.And sorry the last comment is not mine..

Answer (score 0):

I also had this same issue and solved it by changing the id setting

`$("#ddl")`

to

`$('#<%=ddl.ClientID%>')`